# What is the difference between Shopify App Bridge and embed in shopify admin

Tags: shopify

I'm currently starting a project on shopify to make an app and I've noticed that they have released Shopify App Bridge but also I have the option to select Embed in shopify when the app is created.  Is this one in the same or two different ways to display the app in the users store?  If so what are the main differences to help eme select which to use?

Comment: Not even Shopify knows the answer to that right now. It is still a work in progress. If I were you, go with the EASDK setup which is guaranteed to work, and is fully supported. At least until App Bridge is ready to go.

Comment: @David Lazar THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

App Bridge is a replacement to the EASDK. It's the future of Shopify App development. You would use App Bridge to develop your embedded apps instead of EASDK and your existing EASDK apps now use App Bridge under the hood. EASDK will eventually be deprecated but for the foreseeable future will still work as it always has. I encourage you to give App Bridge a try.

Full disclosure, I work on the App Bridge team at Shopify.

Comment: Hi @ApperleyA I'm just starting to use Shopify for a new business (just started to learn today) - I love the fact that modern web technology is being used for app development.  Can you give me an idea of when App Bridge is going to be catering for the customer/visitor front end/POS.  I am looking to build a booking system with specific requirements - App Bridge will work for organising by admin side but need a calendar and/or specific logic for ticket purchases is required for the front end (so I don't know if I should learn the "old" stuff or wait).  Thanks!

Comment: Hey @DanAbdn, I cannot give you an exact timeline for when App Bridge is coming to Point of Sale but it is coming in the near future. For now I would recommend you stick with POSAppSDK (the current way of creating Point of Sale apps) because you'll be able to test your app along the way. Under the hood it will be running on App Bridge and once we release App Bridge for Point of Sale you'll be able to easily port it over.

If you can wait then go ahead and start tinkering with the current App Bridge API to get familiar with the new concepts, then build your app once we release.